# Which op-amp type for a single supply V+?

Tags: operational-amplifier, usb, inverter

No V- from a USB

I am powering an *active bandpass filter* from USB, but don't know from all the choices *which* op-amp characteristic (or *type*) to look for.

Because it's USB, I have no V-, but I've read that you can even get around this by using ground to be lower than the lowest voltage of the input (relatively V-).

I see "rail-to-rail" and "single supply" types, but there are also exceptions to these.

Comment: You could narrow your search down with a list of desired performance requirements.

Comment: There are hundreds of op-amp types that will operate from +5/0 (possibly thousands). You don't need a single supply op-amp to operate from a single supply nor a RRIO, but it may help. A negative rail can also easily be generated, and it may  make things easier so you don't have to bias the filter in the middle of the supply. Anyway, it makes a difference what the required frequency response (hint: it will likely be much higher than the operating frequency), noise, etc.

Comment: What Vpp, BW and load R?

Comment: You seem to be almost there in selecting a component. Since you are working with only a 5V rail it would seem appropriate to select a 'rail-rail' 'single supply' op-amp. Perhaps start here: http://www.ti.com/space-high-reliability/amplifier/operational-amplifiers/products.html#p480=1;2&p1261min=1.3;5